# Why no internet connection on vm using another vm as router?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, router

I'm trying to connect to the internet using virtual machine as router but I'm getting unknown host when pinging google or any other website.

Here are my settings

I am using virtualbox 4.3 and ubuntu 14.04 server
VM1: Will serve as gateway

Network settings on virtualbox:

1st adapter: bridge adapter

2nd adapter: internal network

/etc/network/interfaces configuration

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

2nd VM: Node1

Network settings on virtualbox:

1st adapter: internal network

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

*Note: VM1 can connect to the internet, VM1 and VM2 can ping each other
I have tried enabling /etc/sysctl.conf on both vm's for forwarding. I have checked resolvconf's file and made necessary adjustments even disabled firewall but to no success.

Are there logs that I need to check, settings that I still have to configure, or some other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I would prefer bridge adapter as network adapter for VM1.

I am assuming that since VM1 can connect to the internet, so will VM2 since I have set VM1 to be the router, is my assumption false?

Comment: This is clearly not a programming question, thus off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this in VIM1:

## /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE